# Presto local file connector testing

Tags: presto, presto-jdbc, file-connection, opera-presto

I deployed presto in my local machine and the server is up and running. I'm trying to access a local csv file named "poc.csv" using local file connector. I have created a file called localfile.properties under the etc/catalog folder. So, catalog is localfile and schema is logs(As per the documentation https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/localfile.html)

I can also see the catalog created through presto cli using the command show catalogs; So I believe the catalog has created successfully with no issues.

Now, my question is how does local file connector know which file to read in my local machine (In my case it's poc.csv) and how can I query/access the contents of the poc.csv through presto cli. For the simplicity sake, let's assume we have name and employeeId in poc.csv.

Displaying catalogs through presto cli

[image]

localfile.properties

[image]